# Isn't the quickest way to determine whether a series of number is even permutation or not by the check length of it to see if it's even or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

So, to my understanding of even or odd permutation, I reckon that we can just check the length of the transposition of a series of numbers, to see if it's even or odd to determine if it's even or odd permutation.

Then, with that logic, I'm ok with this `[5, 4, 2, 7, 6, 0, 8, 9, 3, 1]` list of number(length: 10) is not even permutation,

but saying this `[4, 3, 1, 0, 6, 2, 8, 7, 5]`(length: 9) is not a even permutation just drives me insane!!! What's wrong???

A little more background:
I am writing a program to return if the input list of number is even permutation or not, and with my previous logic stated, my program is pretty simple:

```
def is_even(p):
    return len(p) % 2 != 0
```

so the program simply return the result of checking length of numbers by getting the remainder to see if it's odd or even.

But the program pass this `[5, 4, 2, 7, 6, 0, 8, 9, 3, 1]`(length:10) is not a even permutation as well as this `[4, 3, 1, 0, 6, 2, 8, 7, 5]`(length:9)

Could someone tell me the testing system is wrong? thank you... or maybe me? but how? It was not how even permutation to be determined??

Comment: Why your program fails is a question for elsewhere. For how to check evenness, that depends on how the list represents a permutation.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Hi, thanks for checking my question, and I think you are right... but problem is... the question asking for a program to return True or False, simply state that "write a function to determine if the input is even permutation".... and nothing more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the example you give of permutation $p$ :

$$(4, 3, 1, 0, 6, 2, 8, 7, 5), \ \text{meaning that} \ 0 \mapsto 4, 1 \mapsto 3, 2 \mapsto 1, 3 \mapsto 0, 4 \mapsto 6,...$$

Here is an ill-known graphical trick : count the number of intersections in this diagram

[image]

(which is the number of "inversions") As there are $13$ (an odd number) of them, permutation $p$ is odd...

Comment: Hi, Jean, thanks for replying... but I have problem of understanding how number connect to each other like, '0 to 4 ' from above line and '0 to 3' from below line... it's there some kind of rules about permutation that I didn't know? Just like the reply before yours from Hagen, I also don't understand why certain number point to another one... To my understanding, Permutation is Combination with order, hence, there must be a lot of possibility to pair numbers. In a word, I don't understand why 0 point to 4 or 3 not 1 or 2. Or just we can do this way but it won't change the result? Thanks

Comment: I understand it is a question of convention. For example, when you consider permutation $(4,3,1,0,6,2,8,7,5)$ do we agree that you mean $\binom{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}{4,3,1,0,6,2,8,7,5}$, i.e., that $p(0)=4, p(1)=3, p(2)=1,p(3)=0,p(4)=6...$ ?

Comment: oh my god oh my god oh my god!!! when you put the number in that way (I tried to write that format but failed it would be so nice of you if you can also tell me how to write that cool number format)  I just understood everything all of sudden!!! Thank you!!! So you were saying the index pair with the number!!! Oh my god!!! Thank you!!! And your trick here is quite genius!!! Does it have any limitation? Thanks again

Comment: The way I write it is \binom{0,1,2}{4,3,1} (like for a binomial coefficient). Besides, no limiltation for this "trick" ; one must just take care that in case more than two lines cross in the same point, they have to be dis-entangled.

Comment: Thank you again! And I thought to myself that I really need to read more on this topic. Thanks!

Comment: Than you for your thanks ; I appreciate. If you want to have a different view on permutations, see my very recent answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3630810)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $[4, 3, 1, 0, 6, 2, 8, 7, 5]$ stands for the permutation that maps $0\mapsto 4$, $1\mapsto 3$, $2\mapsto 1$, $3\mapsto 0$, etc.
Then this permutation splits intop the following cycles:
$$0\mapsto 4\mapsto 6\mapsto 8\mapsto 5\mapsto 2\mapsto 1\mapsto 3\mapsto 0 $$
and $$7\mapsto 7. $$
Such a cycle with $k$ arrows is even iff $k$ is odd (indeed, the simplest odd permutation is a single transposition $x\mapsto y\mapsto x$ with its two arrows). 
The pemutation as a whole isodd iff this splitting into cycles gives us an odd number of odd cycles. So $[4, 3, 1, 0, 6, 2, 8, 7, 5]$ consists of one odd and an even cycle (and perhaps additional implicit even cycles such as $42\mapsto 42$) and is odd. You simply cannot tell this from the length of the original array.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply and explanation but I am not sure I get that, why and how you get the permutation like what you exemplify:  `0↦4, 1↦3, 2↦1, 3↦0... ` I mean, are these just randomly picks from the original list? And this  `0↦4↦6↦8↦5↦2↦1↦3↦0` is just the several choices from the many examples? I'm so sorry...